# HorizontalAlign.Center not working in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am using an ASP Data Grid I am Binding the data field,Header Text dynamically through code behind(c#).

I am also setting the style of the column dynamically all are working fine but one of the Column Horizontal-align.Center is not working .

I have checked if the style is getting overridden but it is not...

This the block of code giving an issue:

```
        BoundField field4 = new BoundField();
        field4.DataField = dtdata.Tables[0].Columns["data"].ToString();
        field4.HeaderText = "Percentage%";
        field4.DataFormatString = "{0:N1}%";
        field4.SortExpression = "data";
        field4.ItemStyle.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Center;
        grdMarginGrid.Columns.Add(field4);
```

Can anyone help me in recognising where the issue is..

Thanks in advance,
Divya.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think your other styles overriding your new styles.

You can do something like this

Try adding a CSS class to your gridview from your ASPX code, and assign following styles to your class.

```
 <asp:GridView CssClass="grid" runat="server">
    <!-- your options -->
 </asp:GridView>

.grid td, .grid th{
  text-align:center;
}
```

You can add CSS class from code behind also.. 
[MSDN LINK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.webcontrol.cssclass.aspx)

This will set all your columns text to center in your gridview

Answer (score 4):

Give ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" for any field like bound field or Templatefield.

code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Something"  ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" >

 or

<asp:BoundField DataField="" HeaderText="" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
```

Comment: Perfect! Saved me a lot of server-side code :) Just note it is to be placed as above; I tried to put it inside the ItemTemplate tag and got errors...

Answer (score -1):

```
The only solution that works for me :   

 <style>
     .HeaderCentered   {
            text-align: center !important;
        }
 </style>
```

in each boundField in gridview declaration add : HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderCentered"  :

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="idLingua" HeaderText="Lingua" SortExpression="idLingua">
     <HeaderStyle CssClass="HeaderCentered" />
     <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" />
 </asp:BoundField>
```